# Eloquent not removing record from database on AJAX call

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a "like" system for posts and there's an animated button by CSS and three AJAX calls through post.

1. One that will check if the post is already liked and will apply certain style to the button.
2. One that will add a record to the table in case that an user clicks the button.
3. One that will delete the record in case the user click it again.

AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url : '/like/alreadyLiked',
    method : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        slug : '{{Request::segment(2)}}',
        user_id : '{{Auth::user()->user_id}}'
    },
    success : function (data) {
        if(data.display === true){
            $('#likelink').attr('class', 'like active')
        }else{
            $('#likelink').attr('class', 'like');
        }
    }
});

if($('#likelink').hasClass('like') && $('#likelink')[0].classList.length == 1){
    $('#likelink').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : '/like',
            method : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                slug : '{{Request::segment(2)}}',
                user_id : '{{Auth::user()->user_id}}'
            },
            success : function(data){
                if(data.display === true){
                    $('#likelink').attr('class', 'like');
                }
            }
        });

    });
}else{
    $('#likelink').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : '/dislike',
            method : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                slug : '{{Request::segment(2)}}',
                user_id : '{{Auth::user()->user_id}}'
            },
            success : function(data){
                if(data.display === true){
                    $('#likelink').attr('class', 'like');
                }
            }
        });

    });

}
});
```

PHP (Laravel code):

```
    public function hasHeAlreadyLikedThisPost()
{
  if(request()->ajax()){
      $post = Post::where('slug', '=', request()->input('slug'))->first();
      $post_id = $post->post_id;
      $like = Like::where(['user_id' => request()->input('user_id'), 'post_id' => $post_id])->first();
      if($like != null){
        return response()->json(['display' => true]);
      }else{
        return response()->json(['display' => false]);
      }
  }
}

public function addLike()
{
  if(request()->ajax()){
    $slug = request()->input('slug');
    $user_id = request()->input('user_id');

    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    $like = Like::create(array(
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'post_id' => $post->post_id
    ));

    if($like->exists){
      return response()->json(['display' => true]);
    }else{
      return response()->json(['display' => false]);
    }
  }

}

public function dislike()
{
  $slug = request()->input('slug');
  $user_id = request()->input('user_id');
  $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
  $like = Like::where(['post_id' => $post->post_id, 'user_id' => $user_id])->delete();
  return response()->json(['display' => false]);
}
```

The issue is that the "check" and the "insert" calls work but the "delete" one doesn't. In any case it will add a new record to the db and won't change the style.

Comment: Have you tested to see where it is actually reaching that function, and if it is what records are being pulled up in your query for deletion?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have forgot to call first (or get)

```
$like = Like::where(['post_id' => $post->post_id, 'user_id' => $user_id])->first()->delete();
```

where() returns a query,but delete seems to work on eloquent model objects. So to get model object from query so you will call first() (like you did before), or get() to get an array and iterate through it applying delete() on each

Comment: The outcome is the same. It won't delete the record, it will add it again no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting

```
$(document).on('click', '#likelink', function(e)
```

instead of `$('#likelink').on('click', function(e)`